# Xamarin.Mobile iPad Camera Size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mobile

I'm developing an app specifically for the iPad using Xamarin Studio.  One feature is to take a picture using the camera so naturally I'm using Xamarin.Mobile.  Currently when I invoke the  TakePhotoAsync method on the MediaPicker the camera size comes up in an iPhone size window in the middle of my current view.

Is there a way to make the MediaPicker camera be full screen?  Am I missing a setting or a build option or something?

Here is a screen shot

[image: Small Camera View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current (0.7) version, you can call `GetTakePhotoUI` to return a `UIViewController` to handle the display yourself.

Comment: Haven't touched this project in a while but I guess it time to go back and fix this finally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is very dissapointing, but there currently is no way (I know of) to do that. There is another way by using the source code from @miqueldeicaza's Tweetstation app, that is up on Github ([Camera Helper](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/UI/Camera.cs)). The [Xamarin Documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/save_photo_to_app_directory) describes how to use it.

```
TweetStation.Camera.TakePicture(this, (photoObj) => ...
```

You pass in a reference to the ViewController you want the Camera in and it will fill up the entire View.

Comment: +1 for that, I've been looking for a solution for this for ages.